# SQL Server: Better Solution for Column should have fixed length numeric data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to extract row which have only numbers in a specific column but the numbers should only be 6-digit or 12-digit.
I am trying:

```
select * from table where column like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

It works but seems a bit unclean to me.
Please see if anyone can provide better solution.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
where len(column) in (6, 12) and
      column not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

The first condition checks that the length is 6 or 12.  The second checks that all characters are digits.

I should note that this is almost as clear:

```
where column like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' or
      column like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    number bigint

)

INSERT INTO @Table
        ( number )
VALUES  ( 3456157 ), (251236), (785412), (251236475821), (36546)

--Select All rows
SELECT *
FROM @Table

--Just the ones we want
SELECT *
FROM @Table
WHERE
    LEN(number) IN (6, 12)
AND
    number LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```